# What is the difference between сумерки and сумрак?

Tags: выбор-слова, лексикон

As I have been reading about «Ночный Дозор», which I intend to read soon, [Wikipedia hinted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Watch_(Lukyanenko_novel)#The_Twilight_(The_Gloom)) that those words have slightly different meanings. However, that explanation is very subtle and it left me wondering how does it really work and if it's a type of distinction clearly seen by native speakers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Сумерки* means "twilight, dusk", the time of the day right after the sunset or before the sunrise when it's dark but you can still see.

*Сумрак* means "gloom", a dim or dark setting.

The former is a time of the day, the latter is an ambiance.

Comment: That very succint answer surpasses all the dictionaries I have consulted on that matter – thanks :)